# Подскажите в чем ошибка? Не проходят тесты

Tags: python-3.x

При вызове метода is_alive() все воины мертвы. Возможно я что то не так понимаю?

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 50
        self.attack = 5

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.health > 0

class Knight(Warrior):
    def __init__(self):
        Warrior.__init__(self)
        self.attack = 7

def fight(unit_1, unit_2):
    while True:
        if unit_1.is_alive():
            unit_2.health -= unit_1.attack
        else:
            break
        if unit_2.is_alive():
            unit_1.health -= unit_2.attack
        else:
            break
    return unit_1.is_alive()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing

    chuck = Warrior()
    bruce = Warrior()
    carl = Knight()
    dave = Warrior()
    mark = Warrior()

    assert fight(chuck, bruce) == True
    assert fight(dave, carl) == False
    assert chuck.is_alive == True
    assert bruce.is_alive == False
    assert carl.is_alive == True
    assert dave.is_alive == False
    assert fight(carl, mark) == False
    assert carl.is_alive == False

    print("Coding complete? Let's try tests!")
```

Comment: Обратный апостроф в конце второй строки опечатка на SO или в рабочем коде?

Comment: В исходном коде апостроф отсутствует, неудачно залил код на сайт

Comment: Так вы функцию is_alive забываете вызывать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Методом тыка заработало так:

```
assert fight(chuck, bruce)
assert fight(chuck, bruce)
assert not fight(dave, carl)
assert chuck.is_alive()
assert not bruce.is_alive()
assert carl.is_alive
assert not dave.is_alive()
assert not fight(carl, mark)
assert not carl.is_alive()

print (chuck.is_alive())
print (bruce.is_alive())
print (carl.is_alive())
print (dave.is_alive())
print (mark.is_alive())

print("Coding complete? Let's try tests!")
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
False
False
True
Coding complete? Let's try tests!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Померли не все.
Надо будет поизучать Python. Интересный язык оказался...
Проверял в MS VS2019, Python 3.7